# Best Way to create configuration file(config.php) php

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a  database configuration file for my project, but I am not sure if my config.php is secure.

How would I modify this script for a secure connection?

**config.php**

```
<?php
$username="root";
$password="";
$host="localhost";
$database="practise";
?>
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$con=mysql_connect("$host","$username","$password") or die("Server Error");
mysql_select_db("$database") or die("Database error");

if($con==true)
{
    echo "Success";
}
else
{
    mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: nothing wrong with that. other than the fact you're using `mysql_*` (which is deprecated) and not `mysqli` or `pdo`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i find best way to create config.php file for my project

**index.php**

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
try
{
    $host=$config['DB_HOST'];
    $dbname=$config['DB_DATABASE'];
$conn= new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$config['DB_USERNAME'],$config['DB_PASSWORD']);
//new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=mysql", $username, $password);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error:".$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

config.php

```
<?php
$config=array(
'DB_HOST'=>'localhost',
'DB_USERNAME'=>'root',
'DB_PASSWORD'=>'',
'DB_DATABASE'=>'gobinath'
);
?>
```

Comment: it is not the best way. remove the depricated mysql_* functions. use mysqli_* or pdo statements.

Comment: @ris while correct, that has nothing to do with creating and using a config file

Comment: #pala_ and _@ris : update my index.php it's best way?

Answer (score 15):

1) create a config.php

```
define('DBUSER','username');
   define('DBPWD','password');
   define('DBHOST','localhost');
   define('DBNAME','database name');
```

2) db.php

```
 <?php
    include('config.php');
    class db extends mysqli {


        // single instance of self shared among all instances
        private static $instance = null;


        // db connection config vars
        private $user = DBUSER;
        private $pass = DBPWD;
        private $dbName = DBNAME;
        private $dbHost = DBHOST;

        //This method must be static, and must return an instance of the object if the object
        //does not already exist.
        public static function getInstance() {
        if (!self::$instance instanceof self) {
                self::$instance = new self;
        }
            return self::$instance;
        }

        // The clone and wakeup methods prevents external instantiation of copies of the Singleton class,
        // thus eliminating the possibility of duplicate objects.
        public function __clone() {
       trigger_error('Clone is not allowed.', E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        public function __wakeup() {
        trigger_error('Deserializing is not allowed.', E_USER_ERROR);
        }

        private function __construct() {
        parent::__construct($this->dbHost, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->dbName);
        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
                    . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        parent::set_charset('utf-8');

       }
       public function dbquery($query)
        {
            if($this->query($query))
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
        public function get_result($query) 
        {
            $result = $this->query($query);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0){
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            return $row;
            } else
            return null;


        }
    }


    ?>
```

3) uses

```
 require 'db.php';
    $query="select * from tbl_session";
    $sockets = db::getInstance()->get_result($query);
```

or any other query

```
$query="insert into `tbl_chats` (coloum_name) values('".$val."')";
$wisherID = db::getInstance()->dbquery($query);
```

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to use constants for configuration options instead of variables, for three reasons:

1. They are global, so there's no need to inject them into functions as parameters or using a `global` keyword,
2. They can't be changed by the app itself (which can happen by accident if you are not careful and cause some awkward bugs),
3. Good editors offer code completion and can navigate to the line where constant was declared. This makes work with large projects that have a lot of options a bit easier. This applies to global variables as well, but constants are a bit "cleaner" (rule of thumb is to keep the global scope as clean as possible).

Example:

```
<?php

const DB_HOST = 'localhost';
const DB_USER = 'user123';
const DB_PASS = '';
const DB_NAME = 'test';
```

Index:

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php';

$link = new MySQLi(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct methos for my config.php

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
try
{
    $host=$config['DB_HOST'];
    $dbname=$config['DB_DATABASE'];
$conn= new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$config['DB_USERNAME'],$config['DB_PASSWORD']);
//new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=mysql", $username, $password);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error:".$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
$config=array(
'DB_HOST'=>'localhost',
'DB_USERNAME'=>'root',
'DB_PASSWORD'=>'',
'DB_DATABASE'=>'gobinath'
);
?>
```

Comment: Where is the config file? That is what he asked about

Comment: @cwyatt1: added config.php for reference